# how to set to play only HD Videos in YouTube Android Player API

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

How to make YouTube Android Player API play **only HD Videos** [Link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
        YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    if (!wasRestored) {
        Log.v("Mobile Url", "" + mobile_url);
        player.loadVideo(mobile_url);
        player.setFullscreen(true);
        player.setShowFullscreenButton(false);
        player.loadVideo("N1nFoVI3xJM");
    }
}
```

Here I can set the `loadVideo`, `setFullscreen`, `setShowFullscreenButton` I need to load **only HD Videos**. Is that possible? Is any method available to set play only HD videos? If no HD Video found for that ID then I need to show toast as now playing non-HD Videos how to perform this please give some idea or suggestion to achieve this concept

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that..i also need that once .....
[on this like its written](http://www.androidcentral.com/google-pre-announces-youtube-android-player-api-io-finally-bring-proper-youtube-content-android-apps)

It will provide automatic support for fullscreen and orientation change, and will adjust the quality of the stream based upon the strength of the network connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `player.setPlaybackQuality(suggestedQuality:String):Void`

From the YouTube API docs:

> This function sets the suggested video quality for the current video.
>   The function causes the video to reload at its current position in the
>   new quality. If the playback quality does change, it will only change
>   for the video being played. Calling this function does not guarantee
>   that the playback quality will actually change. However, if the
>   playback quality does change, the onPlaybackQualityChange event will
>   fire, and your code should respond to the event rather than the fact
>   that it called the setPlaybackQuality function.

Comment: this player.setPlaybackQuality(suggestedQuality:String):Void is for YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds (which is used in webview) im asking for youtube android player api [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)

Comment: Oh, you are right.  In that case I believe you can use the YouTube Data API to retrieve a list of videos only in HD format.  See here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol?hl=en#hdsp

This would require OAuth.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. i'm using that youtube data API only for that i getting Video ID of HD Videos. even then YouTube Android Player API play non-HD Video for that HD Video ID. it document mention that depends on network capacity and resolution HD Videos will play (im using samsung galaxy s3 even it playing non HD Videos). in my case any customization will work?

Comment: player.setPlaybackQuality(suggestedQuality:String) is only available for javascript how can i access Android app using youtube v3 api on Youtube Player.